# Vimplug fails to install tabnine. Remote moves between counting objects and compressing them

Tags: plugin-vim-plug

My vimrc is moving between

1. `remote: counting objects (1/1)` and
2. `remote: compressing objects (4538/4538)` constantly.

I ran `"PlugUpgrade | PlugClean | PlugInstall | PlugUpdate"` in vimrc, and for some reason `tabnine` plugin can't update / install. It happened before with another plugin, and a reboot solved it for that plugin, but not for this one.

```
" My .vimrc
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'zxqfl/tabnine-vim'
call plug#end()
```

Comment: What's the relevant vimrc snippet setting up this plug-in? Can you use `git` directly to clone this repository somewhere in your machine? (It looks like this might be a `git` problem, so maybe start debugging that first?)

Comment: @filbranden - I added the `.vimrc` snippet. Also, cloning it via git (i.e. `git clone https://github.com/zxqfl/tabnine-vim` seems to work, but excruciatingly slow). Don't really know how to continue from here

Comment: It works for me (although I don't use the plugin so can't confirm functionality, only vim-plug reporting successful installation), but was rather slow as it's a large repository.  Are you sure the issue isn't just that you need to wait a long time on a slow connection?  For what it's worth, it includes a couple of submodules so you may find that `git clone --recursive` takes longer.  Failing that, I would suggest submitting an issue.